# JAVA: concurrent sequence

Tags: java, concurrency, unique, sequence

in my application I have a table to store User informations as Name, Surname, Address, Type (Employee, Manager, Administrator), UniqueNumber.

I need to store in field UniqueNumber for each record in the table User a sequence number between 1 and 100 univocal for Type: so can exist a record with Type = 'Employee' and UniqueNumber=1 and a record with Type='Manager' and UniqueNumber=1 but cannot exist another record with Type='Employee' and UniqueNumber=1.

I was thinking to use a sequence of the database for each Type. This help me to manage concurrency where more users can be inserted a record at the same time.

Is this a good solution?
Is there an alternative?

I see AtomicInteger class but I don't understand how to use it for each Type of my table.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to allow duplicate values for `UniqueNumber` for different `Type`s? Why? I'd just make `UniqueNumber`, well, unique for the whole table. This can be done with whatever autoincrement functionality your database supports.

Comment: it seems its a database question, how is it related to java?

Comment: I need of this in my project. My doubt was indeed whether to do it from the database or from Java. Autoincrement functionality how can manage unique value for each Type in my User table?

Answer (score 1):

AtomicInteger just provides a thread-safe usage of Integer values. 
Your problem has little to do with Java, unless you're creating every single User entity in one pass. If that's the case, you can declare 3 int values and increment them for each entity you're creating (or 3 static or local AtomicInteger values if you need to handle concurrency).
Best way to do it would be to create one sequence per Type, or get the next available value for a given Type using a Max query. --> Depends on your needs

What happens when you have more than 100 values for a Type ?

Comment: Ok. For more than 100 values then cannot store record for that Type.

Answer (score 0):

We can create such code in java, but that's unnecessarily complicated. It involves a `Map` and `AtomicInteger()` and you'd use the `incrementAndGet()` method quite frequently.

On the other hand, you can create two tables. One for `UserTypes`, another for users. Then the users table can have a foreign key to the types. Problem solved on the database level. This is cool because the database will enforce this constraint.

This is how you can do it with MS SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTypes (
  ID INT Identity(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  TypeName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Usr (
  ID INT Identity(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  TypeId INT NOT NULL,
  MoreData VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_types FOREIGN KEY (TypeId) REFERENCES UserTypes (ID)
)
```

Comment: In SQL Server we create `Identity(1, 1)` to generate values starting from 1 and incremented by 1. On other RDBMS-s it might be diffent. Oracle uses sequence.